# a counter example of extension of a continuous function

Tags: general-topology

Let $A\subset X$. Suppose $f:A\rightarrow Y$ is continuous, where $Y$ is Hausdorff. Show that if $f$ can be extended to a continuous function $g:\overline {A}\rightarrow Y$, then $g$ is uniquely determined by $f$. Give an example to show that it may not be possible to extend $f$ to $g$.

For the first question: we write $l=f-g$, which is continuous on $\overline {A}$ and vanishing on $A$. For any $x\in A-\overline {A}$,we can find a sequence of points in $A$, say, $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ such that $l(x_{n})\rightarrow f(x)$, $l(x)$ can only take value $0$ because $Y$ is Hausdorff. Uniqueness drops out.
As for second question, I can't find the counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the solution you present assumes the space is sequential. For general spaces you need to be a bit more careful. For the counter example query, take $X=\mathbb R$ with the usual topology, and $A=X\setminus \{0\}$. Now think of the simplest kinds of functions $f$ that you can. Really simple functions.